# Memory leak issue in Apache drill CTAS command

Tags: memory-leaks, apache-drill

I am getting error while executing `CTAS` command in apache drill.The query works fine when i am running only select command but as soon as I use `CTAS` command it throws Memory leak issue.

Query :

```
create table dfs.test.`temp_count` (user_count) as select t1.data.userParams.imsId as userParams from s3device.`<file>` t1 limit 1
```

Exception :

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: A table or view with given name [temp_count9] already exists in schema [dfs.test] [Error Id: 4c54de50-3875-4534-a3bb-c37a96d21ecb on drill-prd]

Answer (score 0):

Its not a memory leak, its saying the table already exist. You can drop and create table again or use a different table name in CTAS.

```
drop table dfs.test.`temp_count`;
```

Drill supports only create table and not insert/update. Each CTAS will create directory in the file system. You can either delete the directory directly or use `drop table` command to delete it.